# Get the multiple string between two strings in a file

Tags: python-3.x, text-manipulation

I have a ".txt" file where I have a string say "Function supported" and "Function Description"
I have multiple lines between these two string starting with say "-".
How to get each line and apply some changes on it?
To get the substring I can do :

```
substr = list[list.find("Functionality supported")+1:list.find("Functionality     Description")]
print ("Apply h1 to substr\n")
```

Will this helpful and if so how to apply only to text in each line not to "-". Also this "substr" has all those lines, should I apply split on substr , if so how?

thanks in advance
-Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

You can split the substring into separate strings:

```
substrings = substr.split('\n-')
```

Then apply the changes to each of the substrings, and finally join them back:

```
result = '\n-'.join(substrings)
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I want as changes are to change the ".txt" to ".html" file with different formatting style , I mean the headers and change some headers to links and so on.

Comment: @user1389673: It is what you *asked* for. If you want something completely different than what you asked for, I suggest you start a new question, and ask what you want this time. Apparently you want to extract some data from a txt file and generate an HTML file from that. It's a very different question than the one you posed, where you want to "apply some changes" to some lines in a txt file.